# xfreerdp remoteapps, mouse doesn't work correctly

Tags: command-line, mouse, remote-desktop, rdp, x11rdp

I've recently installed Ubuntu Gnome and it is working great, however there are certain Windows applications that I still need to use on a day-to-day basis.
I had an 'older' computer laying around, on which I installed windows 10.
I Then came across a webpage which explained Remoteapps and how they can be used with an ubuntu application called winncon.
Ask ubuntu (which is awesome btw) helped me installing winconn, because its dependencies were quite old.
Winncon then gave me an unresolvable error (-11) which leads me to believe the app is dead in vivid. But then I figured I could do it from the command line.
Using internet acquired knowledge, I used this command to try and connect to my remote computer:
`xfreerdp /v:192.168.1.xxx:3389 /u:xxx /p:xxx /rfx "/app:||explorer" +fonts +aero +menu-anims +smart-sizing +compression +clipboard +window-drag`

This worked except that my mouse wasn't tracked right on the screen. Their website told me to add `/workspace` to my big command. It did not work.
 My mouse on my ubuntu screen does not equal the mouse on the Windows rdp connection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `+smart-sizing` from your command line.

It resizes the picture of remote desktop according to actual `xfreerdp window` size, so the position of cursor on the remote desktop may depend on some proportional ratio, hence the offset becomes visible.